# How to implement my own graphics clipping?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, clipping

I have a task for my Computer Graphics classes. I have to create an application with the following features:

1. There is a dolphin floating on the screen, the user can move it around,
2. The dolphin is filled with some pattern;
3. At the bottom, there are water waves, filled with some color, they move right and left;
4. When the dolphin gets under the waves, the intersection of the dolphin and waves should be filled with some different color.

The task is about clipping. I should have my own functions: `myFill`, which takes as arguments `Color` and `Polygon`, and `myClip`, which takes two `Polygon`s and returns their intersection. In `myFill` I should use scanlines this function has complexity O(1).

The main problem for me is - where to start? Should I use Windows Forms or WPF for this task? If I use WPF, Canvas (InkCanvas?) with some polygons how do I fill them then line by line? What classes will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you ask the teacher.  WPF and Windows Forms are "high-level" graphics libraries that provide polygon filling and clipping built-in.  You need something "low-level" since using either one would defeat the purpose of the assignment.

With that said, you *can* use them so long as you avoid the high-level stuff.  In WPF, you can use the WriteableBitmap class to get access to individual pixels.  In WinForms you can use a PictureBox and a Bitmap to get the same capability.